# What is the level adjustment of steel dragon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I have been trying to decide on a dragon race for a campaign where all players will play as dragon and the steel dragon looked like it would fit me but I can't find its level adjustment in the [Draconomicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draconomicon#3rd_Edition).

Comment: Steel dragons are also known as Greyhawk dragons, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### +2 (wyrmling), +3 (very young), +4 (young), +4 (juvenile), — (others)

The steel dragon's 3.5 update occurred in *Dragons of Faerun,* printed in 2006. You can find them on page 140. The *Draconomicon* was 2003, so it wouldn't have the stats and LA listed for these dragons.